# 'Not' operation on Date range filter in Kibana Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, date-range, kibana-7

I am trying to create a visualization on Kibana to track entities which are active in the past week but not active in the last two days. As I have timestamp available on each document I could easily create a visualization to show entities that got hit in the past week. It shows all the entities including those where hit in the past two days. I want to exclude these entities which got hit in the past two days.

I want something like this :

`Date Range (now-7d  to now-2d)  and NOT(now-2d - now)`

Specifically, I am looking for a help to do the **negation** operation on the date range.

here is how my filter look like:

[image]

Comment: How could a document be in the range `now-7d  to now-2d` AND the range `now-2d - now` ? It's either or, unless I missed something

Comment: I am looking for the range `now-7d to now-2d`  AND  the range `NOT(now-2d - now)`  i am looking for the `NOT` part

Comment: If a document is in the `now-7d to now-2d` part, it is necessarily also in `NOT(now-2d - now)`... if the document is not in `now-7d to now-2d` then the AND condition will not select it anyway. I don't see how it's possible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the needs, but I think you should not try to do it in an aggregation, and you should do it in a filter.
You can save a filter with a visualization.

By the way, I think that a filter *(now-7d  to now-2d)* will do the job and you don't need *!(now-2d - now)*
The query will be

```
{
  "range": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "gte": "now-7d/d",
      "lt": "now-2d/d"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

In a range aggregate i think that !*(now-2d -tonow)* is = to *infinite to now-2d*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But this doesn't hep me, the above filter is what I have applied. I want to exclude those entities which got hit earlier this week and hit again in the past two days. I am trying to make a visualization for less active entity. the above filter fails to do so. it displays the most recent entity as less active if it had an activity before two days, which is wrong. I am looking for the Not part specifically.

Comment: I still think I don't really understand our needs.
Either the second image i just added on the post is your answer either what you need is a serial diff aggregation, to subtract a period from another.

Comment: @manoj - Maybe You could provide more detail to help us find a solution for you

Comment: 1) I want to create a visualization (data table) to show inactive entities 2) An entity is inactive if it doesn not have any hit in the past 2 days, but has hit with in 7 days and prior to 2 days.    I  hope I made my requirement clear.    PS: I am not looking for a filter in the top bar, But I am trying to create a visualization with Date range as one of the Split filter

Comment: it's more clear. so what you want here is "last hit date is between 7d and 2d". Could it be achieve with a max aggregation on the date? and then manipulate this date?

Comment: I think max aggregation on date with a date range will select the last hit of the entity in that date range only. Which won't be enough. For max to work, max should be outside the date range (that is mac of all ) and then apply date range in top of max. Is there a way I can do that?